# Python IDLE using pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been recently testing out basic tutorials on pandas and I am using IDLE to run my scripts. I have two questions concerning pandas. The first question is, how do you auto-fit columns so that I do not have to auto-fit columns so all data is shown? Second is, does IDLE display data frames?

The code below is how I am exporting my data to a csv file.

```
    df.to_csv('current_flats.csv',index=False,encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

This is the output I receive in the IDLE output when I print the data frame.

```
print(df)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                              Title  ...       Price
0   Flamsteed Close, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, CB1  ...  £1,550 pcm
1                       Chariot Way, Cambridge, CB4  ...  £1,200 pcm
2                          Highdene Road, Cambridge  ...    £995 pcm
3                          Victoria Road, Cambridge  ...    £950 pcm
4                     Cherry Hinton Road, Cambridge  ...    £795 pcm
5                    Beaufort Place, Thompsons Lane  ...  £1,975 pcm
6                           Impala Drive, Cambridge  ...    £950 pcm
7                            Lilac Court, Cambridge  ...  £1,175 pcm
8                          Lucerne Close, Cambridge  ...    £715 pcm
9               Pym Court, Cromwell Road, Cambridge  ...  £1,495 pcm
10                                  Hampden Gardens  ...  £1,550 pcm
11                       Ditchburn Place, Cambridge  ...  £1,050 pcm
12                Leys Lodge, Union Lane, Cambridge  ...  £1,250 pcm
13       83 The Belvedere, Homerton Street, CB2 0NU  ...  £1,250 pcm
14                        Mill Road, Cambridge, CB1  ...  £1,100 pcm
15                                  Gilmerton Court  ...  £1,300 pcm
16                                      Corrie Road  ...    £895 pcm
17                   The Belvedere, Homerton Street  ...  £1,250 pcm
18                        Primrose Lodge, Cambridge  ...    £825 pcm
19                        Mulgrave Court, Cambridge  ...  £1,450 pcm
20                                St Bedes Crescent  ...    £995 pcm
21                                      Hope Street  ...    £700 pcm
22                      Queen Ediths Way, Cambridge  ...  £1,250 pcm
23                    Chesterton Road,Cambridge,CB4  ...    £975 pcm
24     York Terrace, Cambridge, Cambridgeshire, CB1  ...  £1,050 pcm

[25 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `set_option` property in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)

df = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
print(df)
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using Jupyter notebook when coding Pandas. It is same situation with Jupyter: it shows only part of the columns and rows if DataFrame is large.

If I want to see all columns and rows then I just use pd.to_csv -function and open the file in Excel or some other csv viewer. This way I can see all cols and rows.

I am not sure if IDLE can be configured to view all data.

Comment: I have not found a way to actually view the data as a data frame like for example Spyder does. If I could instead find a way for when saving the data in a csv file, I can adjust the column width etc it would be a good alternative. Thanks again